# Setting socket buffer size in Apache HttpClient

Tags: apache, sockets, buffer, apache-httpclient-4.x

How do you set the socket buffer size in Apache HttpClient version 4.3.3?

Comment: Are you talking about SO_SNDBUF and SO_RECVBUF parameters or the session buffer used by HTTP connections?

Comment: I am talking about the SO_SNDBUF and SO_RECVBUF parameters

Answer (score 2):

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE, 128 * 1024);

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    String res = null;
    try
    {
        post.addHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        post.addHeader("Content-Name", selectedFile.getName());
        post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(fileBytes));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        res = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: That's for pre 4.3, I believe `client.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE, 128 * 1024);` was deprecated

Answer (score 1):

You create a custom ConnectionConfig object with your desired buffer size and pass it as a parameter when creating your HttpClient object. For example:

```
ConnectionConfig connConfig = ConnectionConfig.custom()
        .setBufferSize(DESIRED_BUFFER_SIZE)
        .build();

try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultConnectionConfig(connConfig)
            .build()) {

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://google.com");
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(get)) {
        // Do something with the response
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error transferring file: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Error connecting to server: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

There are lots of other configurable options available, [checkout the API](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html) for the full list.